# Set delay for tumbling window trigger on a pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a **tumbling window trigger** to run **every 1 hour** and **10 minutes delay** before the pipeline starts executing.

I created a test trigger with **time interval** of 5 minutes and **delay** of 10 minutes.

I expected the pipeline to run every 15 minutes (5 min interval + 10 min delay).

What I actually see in the Monitor section of the *pipelines Runs* and *Triggers Runs* that it runs **every 5** minutes.

Isn't the delay should delay the pipeline execution?

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Updated**

Here's my trigger template:

```
{
        "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/trigger_test')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "annotations": [],
            "runtimeState": "Started",
            "pipeline": {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "exportData",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
            "typeProperties": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 5,
                "startTime": "2021-07-25T07:46:00Z",
                "delay": "00:10:00",
                "maxConcurrency": 50,
                "retryPolicy": {
                    "intervalInSeconds": 30
                },
                "dependsOn": []
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/pipelines/exportData')]"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the cron setting you used in your pipeline. As written, it's difficult to ascertain what the specific issue is.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - added the trigger template

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a concrete example and the docs are not very clear in terms for terminology.

From what I understand, when one trigger window finished running, the next trigger window starts running **regardless of the delay specified**.

According to the docs, "the delay doesn't alter the window startTime" which I assume means what I have mentioned above.